# Compiler Design - How does does automatic type casting occur when multiple cast levels away

Tags: types, casting, compiler-construction, implicit-conversion

[image]

To convert from `byte` to `short`, would I be right to assume there's some kind of method being called in the background with the signature:

`short byte2Short(byte b);`

But what about the situation where a `byte` has to be converted to a `long`? I.e. in the conversion diagram they are not connected directly by a arrow.

Is there a specific method that converts a `byte` into a `long` such as:

`long byte2Long(byte b);`

Or instead does it call a chain of methods that converts the byte as follows:

1. `short byte2Short(byte b);`
2. `int short2Int(short s);`
3. `long int2Long(int i);`

So essentially my question is, if converting from a byte to a long, is the conversion direct like:
`byte -> long`

Or is it indirect like:
`byte -> short -> int -> long`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion happens directly, i.e., `byte -> long`.

[C implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)

> If the types have the same signedness (both signed or both unsigned), the operand whose type has the lesser conversion rank1 is implicitly converted2 to the other type.